# how to make discord bot send a new user DM?

Tags: node.js, discord

I Know How to Use

```
bot.on("guildMemberAdd" ,(message, member) => {
    bot.channels.find('name', "chat").send("Welcome")
}
```

But How Could You Make It Send The User A DM When They Join The Server

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) is should be as simple as this:

```
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    member.send("Welcome")
        .catch(console.error);
});
```