# How to send a DM to new members of a discord server using a discord bot (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, dm

I have tried using a few ways all of which did not cause any error messages (or if they did they were easy to fix) but they still did not send the DM.

the way that I'm most confident of is:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!'
    )
```

There could be multiple issues with this but for the moment I'm stuck on the second line; it doesn't actually activate if a user joins my server (I tested this by just shoving a print command straight after it and watching the output as I joined the server on an alt). Any ideas would be appreciated. :)

oh yeah I tried another way that might work but I couldn't get to: [how to make discord bot send a new user DM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427182/how-to-make-discord-bot-send-a-new-user-dm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since managed to get this to work and am still unsure of what wasn't working, my best guess is that something wasn't working correctly somewhere else in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!')
```

All this will do is send it to the member that joined.

Comment: the second line still doesnt work. "async def on_member_join(member):" still doesnt do anything. it just skips the whole event and doesnt catch when people join

Answer (score 0):

This is a little old, but when I ran into this issue it was because I was working from older examples that did not include the need for intents.

While the below is very blanket and likely overkill(I am just in local dev atm), this fixed the issue:

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
intents.messages = True

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(
        f'{client.user.name} has connected to discord!'
    )

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send(f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```